# Call Clang without preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm writing a high level language compiler. I'm currently using C as my target and then using clang for final compilation and linking. I'm going to use the Boehm garbage collector. I may switch the target to C++ so as I can use the C++ exception handling runtime. Aside from that I'm not intending to use any of C++'s extra features.

My knowledge of Clang is limited but I understand it is intended to be more modular than gcc and has a more liberal licence if one wants to link the compiler into proprietary code. I'm currently writing my Compiler in Scala and calling the Clang application through an exec system call. However I can use JNI to call native C / C++ functions if needed.

So is there a way to skip the pre processor and template evaluation phases of the Clang compiler and hence save compilation time. I don't need to use header files as I can generate the required function prototypes for each C / C++ source file.

Comment: Kinda unrelated, but have you checked out LLVM?

Comment: @Qix: Isn't LLVM the basis of `clang`?

Comment: I'd be surprised if, without includes, the preprocessing stage adds much to compilation time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not directly; clang is a C/C++/ObjC frontend for LLVM. Theoretically one could adapt clang to use a different backend, though as it stands LLVM is the best one out there (arguably, of course :)). If one is writing a high level language, usually you go straight to LLVM IR instead of mucking around with clang.

Comment: And +1 to @abligh's comment; preprocessing shouldn't take any time at all, relatively speaking.

Comment: Rename the source file to file.i.  clang should treat it as already preprocessed.

Comment: I doubt that template processing code can be disabled as easily as the preprocessor; it's likely to be much more tightly integrated into the compiler.

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: @n.m. That's a totally unrelated saying for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Qix Didn't he say he's trying to save compilation time? Let me check... yep, he did.

Comment: @n.m. That statement has to do with runtime optimization. Please research it. What the OP is doing is not premature optimization. While you're at it, read the first post in its entirety, please.

Comment: @Qix Please. Runtime optimization? What other kinds of optimization are out there? OP wants to run something (a compiler). That's "runtime" if you insist. He wants it to run faster. That's "optimization". He wants it to run faster without (as I understand) measuring how fast/slow it really is or determining what factors might slow things down. That's "premature". I have read the post in its entirety several times over and I still don't see how [this passage of Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes) doesn't apply to it. If you know better, share.

Comment: Can't tell if you're a troll, or....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, clang and gcc will determine input language based on file extension. If your input file's extension is `.i`, it will be interpreted as preprocessed C; `.ii` is preprocessed C++.

You can use the `-x <language>` parameter to explicitly specify what language the input file is in. For C preprocessed input, you can specify `<language>` as `cpp-output`. For C++ preprocessed input, you can specify `<language>` as `c++-cpp-output`.

I can't find clang documentation for this, but since clang and gcc have pretty much identical user interfaces, [here's a link to the gcc documentation for specifying language using file extension and `-x`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html).

I don't know of a way to skip C++ template expansion.

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Clang accepts a cpp-output language, but still runs the preprocessor as usual.